# How can I use an MPU6050 with Arduino to measure linear speed?

Tags: arduino-nano

I need to measure linear speed of a body which travels 1000 m forward and backward recursively. How can I use an MPU6050 with Arduino Nano to measure the linear speed of a moving object? (the object does not have any rotation). I tried my best, but I was not able to measure linear speed, can I get sample source code?

Comment: You can't. Integration of horizontal accelerations will give you a considerable error.

Comment: Exactly. Error will add up making your measurement completely useless. On the other hand, I assume 1000m is somewhere in the open. So adding GPS to the accelerometer, and using Kálmán filter to use both sensors will give you acceptable results. Or if your movement is on rails or wheels, using an encoder will be even better.

Comment: The problem is small errors and drift. If your acceleration reading is off by 5% for each reading, that error compounds and after just a few readings the error completely swamps the calculated velocity and position readings. You can't sense velocity using an accelerometer, so you have no way to tell if you are moving at 0 kpm or 1000 kpm.